# Joining two tables to turn two stored procedures into one SQL

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, join

I am trying to shorten my stored procedures, I have a feeling that I could use one instead of two.

The first table (`dbo.Table1`) has:

```
ProductID, DiscountID
```

And the second table (`dbo.Table2`) has:

```
Description, DiscountAmount and DiscountID
```

I am trying to get the discount amount, but I only have the product Id. At the moment I am using a stored proc to call the first table for the `discountID`. I then use the `discountID` in a second stored proc to get the `DiscountAmount` from the second table.

Is there are a way to combine these two stored procedures so I can use the `productID` to get the `DiscountAmount` in one procedure?

Comment: Just a side remark: It looks strange to see a discount amount rather than a discount percentage in table2. It would be more typical to see "10% discount on computers" than "50$ discount on computers". But you do use one discount for more than one product, yes? (I am asking, because it would make no sense to have a separate table for discounts, when there is a 1:1 relation rather than 1:n.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
SELECT t2.DiscountAmount 
FROM Table2 t2 inner join Table1 t1
on t2.DiscountID = t2.DiscountID
WHERE t1.ProductID = @ProductId
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/265d1/2)

Comment: Please limit your use of inline code formatting (i.e., the backticks) to things that are actually code (like keywords and identifiers). Here, you've made `Fiddle` look like it's code, when it is really just a link to an external website. I looked through some of your recent edits, and you've done the same thing there. Like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23828424/revisions). `check the documentation` is clearly not code, so it shouldn't be formatted that way. If you *need* to emphasize something, use bold or italics. But be careful with over-emphasis!

Comment: @CodyGray, fair point, I do tent to use this with highlighting - I will edit my posts.

Answer (score 0):

You have a stored procedure that does nothing else than

```
select discountid from table1 where productid = @productid;
```

and another doing only

```
select discountamount from table2 where discountid  = @discountid;
```

That looks a bit oversized to me ;-)

But yes, of course you can combine the two statements:

```
select discountamount from table2 where discountid  = 
   (select discountid from table1 where productid = @productid);
```